# Does a function exist which is not Riemann integrable and satisfies the given condition:

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration, dirichlet-forms

I am looking for a function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is not Riemann integrable such that
$$\sum_{k=0}^n |f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})|^2 <1$$ for every choice of $0=x_0\le x_1 \le \cdots \le x_n =1$

I tried the function

$$f(x)= \begin{cases} 0 ,  x \in \mathbb{Q}\\
x^2 ,  x \in \mathbb{Q} ^c
\end{cases}$$

Does this function satisfy the given condition?  I tried many choices of partitions for this function and it seems to satisfy the given condition.  I couldn't get a contradiction in any of those cases. Can anyone help to prove or disprove the existence of such function?Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't your condition imply that $f$ is bounded and has at most countably many discontinuities? and is therefore Riemann integrable?

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "ca.classical-analysis-and-odes". I added this tag now.

Comment: Your overall question is answered, but on the side question of your specific function $f$: Fix any $x \in (0,1)$, and small rational $\epsilon$; then take the partition $x \leq x+ \sqrt{2}\epsilon \leq x+2\epsilon \leq x + (2+\sqrt{2})\epsilon \cdots \leq x+2n\epsilon \leq x + (2n+\sqrt{2})\epsilon$.  For $n \geq \frac{1}{x^4}$, the sum of squares of jumps will be $>1$; now any $\epsilon < (1-x)/3n$ makes this fit. Idea: near $x$, $f$ jumps by about $x^2$ between rational and irrational values; since both are dense, you can take as many such jumps as you need near $x$.

Comment: Do you have the textbook from which you got the idea.

Comment: @Euler-Masceroni this is not from a textbook it's from a competitive exam for research studies

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your condition implies that $f$ is Riemann integrable. To see this, consider a partition
$$0=a_0<a_1<\dotsb <a_n=1,$$
and pick two arbitrary sample points $s_j,t_j\in[a_{j-1},a_j]$ from each subinterval. The difference of the corresponding Riemann sums can be estimated by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality as
$$\left|\sum_{j=1}^n (f(s_j)-f(t_j))(a_j-a_{j-1})\right|\leq\left(\sum_{j=1}^n |f(s_j)-f(t_j)|^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{j=1}^n(a_j-a_{j-1})^2\right)^{1/2}.$$
On the right-hand side, the first sum is less than $1$ by the initial assumption, while the second sum is at most $\max_j (a_j-a_{j-1})$. Therefore,
$$\left|\sum_{j=1}^n (f(s_j)-f(t_j))(a_j-a_{j-1})\right|\leq\max_j (a_j-a_{j-1})^{1/2}.$$
This means that if the mesh of the partition is less than $\epsilon^2$, then the lower and upper Darboux sums of the partition differ by less than $\epsilon$. This implies that $f$ is Riemann integrable (by a well-known criterion).

Comment: That's a very neat proof. Thank you :)

Answer (score 9):

A function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ which satisfies the given condition is Riemann integrable. By the [Lebesgue–Vitali theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral), it will suffice to show that $f$ is bounded and continuous almost everywhere. It is obviously bounded; I will show that its set of points of discontinuity is countable.

If $D$ is the set of points of discontinuity of $f$, then $D=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty D_n$ where $D_n=\{x\in[0,1]:\omega_f(x)\gt\frac1n\}$ and $\omega_f(x)$ is the [oscillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillation_(mathematics)) of $f$ at $x$. The stated condition implies that $D_n$ has fewer than $n^2$ elements, whence $D$ is countable.